# Converting PHP function to Python

Tags: php, python

I am trying to port over the below PHP function to Python.  However I am receiving the following error:  line 189, in detectOnSubImage
rect = rects[i_rect]
IndexError: list index out of range

Rects receives the list located at current_node[1]

> rects = current_node[1]

And the while loop would not go out of range past the length of the list rects

```
while i_rect < len(rects):    
       i_rect = i_rect+1    
       rect = rects[i_rect]
```

What did I miss when porting over this PHP function to Python and what would be the correct Python code equivalent?

PHP code: (below)

```
protected function detectOnSubImage($x, $y, $scale, $ii, $ii2, $w, $iiw, $inv_area)
{
    $inv_area";
    $mean  = ($ii[($y+$w)*$iiw + $x + $w] + $ii[$y*$iiw+$x] - $ii[($y+$w)*$iiw+$x] - $ii[$y*$iiw+$x+$w])*$inv_area;
    $vnorm = ($ii2[($y+$w)*$iiw + $x + $w]
              + $ii2[$y*$iiw+$x]
              - $ii2[($y+$w)*$iiw+$x]
              - $ii2[$y*$iiw+$x+$w])*$inv_area - ($mean*$mean);
    $vnorm = $vnorm > 1 ? sqrt($vnorm) : 1;
    $passed = true;
    for ($i_stage = 0; $i_stage < count($this->detection_data); $i_stage++) {
        $stage = $this->detection_data[$i_stage];
        $trees = $stage[0];

        $stage_thresh = $stage[1];
        $stage_sum = 0;

        for ($i_tree = 0; $i_tree < count($trees); $i_tree++) {
            $tree = $trees[$i_tree];
            $current_node = $tree[0];
            $tree_sum = 0;
            while ($current_node != null) {
                $vals = $current_node[0];
                $node_thresh = $vals[0];
                $leftval = $vals[1];
                $rightval = $vals[2];
                $leftidx = $vals[3];
                $rightidx = $vals[4];
                $rects = $current_node[1];

                $rect_sum = 0;
                for ($i_rect = 0; $i_rect < count($rects); $i_rect++) {
                    $s = $scale;
                    $rect = $rects[$i_rect];
                    $rx = ($rect[0]*$s+$x)>>0;
                    $ry = ($rect[1]*$s+$y)>>0;
                    $rw = ($rect[2]*$s)>>0;
                    $rh = ($rect[3]*$s)>>0;
                    $wt = $rect[4];
                    $r_sum = ($ii[($ry+$rh)*$iiw + $rx + $rw]
                              + $ii[$ry*$iiw+$rx]
                              - $ii[($ry+$rh)*$iiw+$rx]
                              - $ii[$ry*$iiw+$rx+$rw])*$wt;
                    $rect_sum += $r_sum;
                }
                $rect_sum *= $inv_area;
                $current_node = null;
                if ($rect_sum >= $node_thresh*$vnorm) {
                    if ($rightidx == -1) {
                        $tree_sum = $rightval;
                    } else {
                        $current_node = $tree[$rightidx];
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($leftidx == -1) {
                        $tree_sum = $leftval;
                    } else {
                        $current_node = $tree[$leftidx];
                    }
                }
            }
            $stage_sum += $tree_sum;
        }
        if ($stage_sum < $stage_thresh) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

Python code: (below)

```
def detectOnSubImage(self, x, y, scale, ii, ii2, w, iiw, inv_area):  
    mean  = (ii[(y+w)*iiw + x + w] + ii[y*iiw+x] - ii[(y+w)*iiw+x] - ii[y*iiw+x+w])*inv_area  
    vnorm = (ii2[(y+w)*iiw + x + w] + ii2[y*iiw+x] - ii2[(y+w)*iiw+x] - ii2[y*iiw+x+w])*inv_area - (mean*mean)  
    vnorm = sqrt(vnorm) if vnorm > 1 else 1  
    #var foo = (test) ? "True" : "False";  
    #foo = "True" if test else "False"  
    passed = True  
    #for i_stage in xrange(0, i_stage < (len(self.detection_data)), i_stage= i_stage+1):  
    i_stage=0  
    while i_stage < len(self.detection_data):  
        i_stage= i_stage+1  
        stage = self.detection_data[i_stage]  
        trees = stage[0]  
        stage_thresh = stage[1]
        stage_sum = 0

        #for i_tree in xrange( 0, i_tree < len(trees), i_tree= i_tree+1):
        i_tree=0
        while i_tree < len(trees):
            i_tree= i_tree+1
            tree = trees[i_tree]
            current_node = tree[0]
            tree_sum = 0
            while (current_node != None):
                vals = current_node[0]
                node_thresh = vals[0]
                leftval = vals[1]
                rightval = vals[2]
                leftidx = vals[3]
                rightidx = vals[4]
                rects = current_node[1]
                rect_sum = 0
                #for i_rect in xrange(0, i_rect < len(rects), i_rect = i_rec+1):
                i_rect = 0
                while i_rect < len(rects):
                    i_rect = i_rect+1
                    s = scale
                    rect = rects[i_rect]
                    rx = (rect[0]*s+x)>>0
                    ry = (rect[1]*s+y)>>0
                    rw = (rect[2]*s)>>0
                    rh = (rect[3]*s)>>0
                    wt = rect[4]

                    r_sum = (ii[(ry+rh)*iiw + rx + rw] + ii[ry*iiw+rx] - ii[(ry+rh)*iiw+rx] - ii[ry*iiw+rx+rw])*wt
                    rect_sum = rect_sum + r_sum
                rect_sum = rect_sum * inv_area
                current_node = None
                if (rect_sum >= node_thresh*vnorm):
                    if (rightidx == -1):
                        tree_sum = rightval
                    else: 
                        current_node = tree[rightidx]
                else:
                    if (leftidx == -1):
                        tree_sum = leftval
                    else:
                        current_node = tree[leftidx]
            stage_sum = stage_sum + tree_sum
        if (stage_sum < stage_thresh):
            return false
    return True
```

Here is the tree structure and other var_dumps from within the PHP code which shows a multi-dimensional array

$tree = $trees[0]
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> float(0.00432723) [1]=> float(0.0383819) [2]=> float(-1) [3]=> int(-1) [4]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(-1) } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(9) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(2) } } } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> float(0.0130762) [1]=> float(0.896526) [2]=> float(0.262931) [3]=> int(-1) [4]=> int(-1) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(8) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(14) [4]=> int(-1) } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(8) [1]=> int(11) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(7) [4]=> int(2) } } } }

$current_node = $tree[0]
array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> float(0.00432723) [1]=> float(0.0383819) [2]=> float(-1) [3]=> int(-1) [4]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(-1) } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(9) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(2) } } }

$vals = $current_node[0]
array(5) { [0]=> float(0.00432723) [1]=> float(0.0383819) [2]=> float(-1) [3]=> int(-1) [4]=> int(1) }

$rects = $current_node[1]
array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(-1) } [1]=> array(5) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(9) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(2) } }

$rect = $rects[0]
array(5) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(16) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(-1) }

Comment: You set `current_node` to contain the value of `tree[0]`, so it has a length of 1 (only element zero exists in it). What is the structure of `tree` in php and what is it in python? (`print tree` before the `current_node` assignment). If that is a special object, it might be "packaged" differently. (For example, `[[1,2,3]]` will not have element 1.)

Comment: In PHP $tree shows as an Array with a length of 2  $tree = $trees[$i_tree];
    print "Tree: $tree";
    $length = count($tree);
    print "Tree Array Length: $length";

Comment: And does that structure survive in python? Python is not great with lists as a surrogate for multi-dimensional arrays. I think we need to see the part where `trees` is defined or imported in Python.

Comment: thank Beroe, I've included PHP var_dumps of tree, current_node, vals, rects, and rect to show how the multi-dimensional array is structured in tree and then indexed by current_node, vals, rects, and rect. If I had the same tree multi-dimensional list/array structure and values defined, what Python code would properly index through it in a similar manner?

Comment: How are you loading the `trees` value in Python? Can you show what `print trees` or `print tree` gives *in Python*. It might be as simple as adding another `[0]` or as complicated as using a Numpy array instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice beroe and I've figured out my coding mistakes by following your advice using print trees, print tree, print current_node, print rects, and print rec and comparing to the PHP output.  Turns out my entire sequencing through the stage, trees, tree, rects was off by 1 because of the way I constructed my while loops for i_stage, i_tree, and i_rect because I increment them by 1 right after the while declaration which means the indexing is off by 1 ahead and therefore it goes out of range.  Thanks again for the advice and pointers!  Would like to give you credit for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this, I recommend printing out the entire structure of the `tree` and `trees` variables (and others) within Python and in the PHP code. This will let you compare what assignments and indexing you need to do to make the code compatible. I have had issues in the past where it was just a matter of adding one more `[0]` to the end of an array assignment, because it was nested one level deeper in the PHP or JSON or whatever than I anticipated.

Good luck!